# passing parameters to dynamic drop down function jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a for loop which generates few 'a' tag buttons and few divisions. I am trying to write a function in which with a toggle effect. If I click on a specific a tag only the corresponding div tag should get toggled. I am trying to pass a dynamic value to this function but it doesn't work. Here is the code. Please help. Thank you.

```
<html>
<header>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css"> 
.hideonly
{
padding:50px;
display:none;
}
</style>
</header>
<body>
<?php
$num_row = 5; //dynamic value
$i = 0;
$header_title = "";
    for ($i=0;$i<$num_row;$i++)
      {
        $header_title = $i; // Displaying all the headers and menus for the hotel.
        echo "<div>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<a class = \"menu-header-2\" href=\"#\">$header_title</a>";
        echo "<div id = \".$i.\" class = \"hideonly\" >Hello World!</div>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "</div>";
      } 
?>
</body>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".menu-header-2").click(function($i){
    $("#" . $i).slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Just an fyi, the callback function you pass to the click handler is an event object, not the id of the clicked element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution should work for you.

`$(this).next('div').slideToggle('fast');`

There are some things that you are doing wrong.

1. Starting an `id` with a number. In fact your `id` is the number. It should start with a letter
2. Having the script `after` the body. Typically it should be either in the `head` element or just before `body` ends
3. In the `.click()` function, you are passing `$i`. It makes no sense. You should be using `event` instead. In this case, you don't really need it and can have the method without passing anything to it. This is for times when you would use the `event` parameter.